# Field is not writeable: Account_Merchant__c.Merchant_Name__c

Tags: apex, soql

I'm trying to chage the value of Account_Merchant__r.Merchant_Name__c, if it's blank to 'Missing name'. But i get the error Field is not writeable: Account_Merchant__c.Merchant_Name__c. What is could be the problem ? Here is my code.

```
public List<SBQQ__QuoteLine__c> populateData(){
    populateData = [SELECT Id, name, Heading_Name__c, Market_Name__c, Account_Merchant__r.Merchant_Name__c, SBQQ__StartDate__c, SBQQ__EndDate__c, SBQQ__Product__r.Is_Setup_Fee__c,Final_Price__c,
                    PDF_Net_Saving__c, PDF_Net_Price__c, SBQQ__Quote__c,  Final_Product_Name__c
                    FROM SBQQ__QuoteLine__c
                    WHERE SBQQ__Quote__c = :quoteId AND PDF_Is_To_Display_in_Recurring__c = true];
    for(SBQQ__QuoteLine__c line : populateData){
        if(String.isBlank(line.Account_Merchant__r.Merchant_Name__c)){
            line.Account_Merchant__r.Merchant_Name__c = 'Missing name';
        }
    }
    return populateData;
}
```

Comment: The problem is quite simply that Salesforce has decided that the field isn't writable. As for why that is, you should look at the field in question for additional information. Formula fields, for example, are always read-only.

Answer (score 0):

The issue looks like you're trying to update the related Account record via the reference to this field on the related Quote Line Item record. To complete this, there are a couple of ways that you could do this:

1. Capture a list of Accounts that need updating and populate the 'Missing name' value as part of the process that this code is a part of.
2. Update the process for creating/capturing Accounts to either auto-populate the Missing name value or make the field required